# How to put Java object in Couchbase's JsonObject in one operation

Tags: couchbase-java-api

With `Couchbase's` jsonObject we can create object with certain fields:

```
import    com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject
...
JsonObject content = JsonObject.create().put("some", "value");
```

The put function has several `String & value` options such as double, int, String etc, [as can be seen here](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.0.0/index.html?com/couchbase/client/java/document/json/JsonObject.html).

I was looking for a way to put a whole object in it. Something like:

```
Cat cat = new Cat(.....)
JsonObject content = JsonObject.create().put(cat);
```

Is there a way to do it and not to iterate over all of Cat's fields?

Answer (score 3):

So here is how it can be done:

```
Cat cat = new Cat(...);
String asJson = gson.toJson(cat);
JsonObject.fromJson(asJson);
```

Comment: Yup! Another neat trick is that with SDK 3, you might not need to use JsonObject at all. SDK 3 supports data binding; you can call `collection.upsert("felix", cat)`, and the SDK will use the `JsonSerializer` configured on the `ClusterEnvironment` to convert `cat` to JSON. The default serializer uses a repackaged version of Jackson; that's good enough for simple binding, but if you want to get serious, you can bring your own version of Jackson. If you prefer Gson, you could write your own `JsonSerializer` that delegates to Gson.